# Sending XML via php and getting back a response

Tags: php, xml

I'm having problems sending the follwoing XML via PHP. I can't seem to get the script right it just comes back with a blank page. Any suggestions would be great. I am not coming up with any errors just nothing seems to happen.

```
POST /PubServices/WebServices/PublicationWebServices.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.geminifund.com
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length


POST /PubServices/WebServices/PublicationWebServices.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.geminifund.com
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset= utf-8    
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<soap12:Body>
 <GetHistroricalNav xmlns="http://www.geminifund.com/webservices/">
   <startDate>dateTime</startDate>
   <endDate>dateTime</endDate>
   <portfolio>string</portfolio>
    </GetHistroricalNav>
  </soap12:Body>
 </soap12:Envelope>
```

and my script is as follows

```
<?php

$url = "http://www.geminifund.com";

$post_string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rootNode>
<innerNode>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetHistroricalNav xmlns="http://www.geminifund.com/webservices/">
  <startDate>2011-06-30</startDate>
  <endDate>2011-7-30</endDate>
  <portfolio>1778/portfolio>
</GetHistroricalNav>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
</innerNode>
 </rootNode>';


 $header  = "POST /PubServices/WebServices/PublicationWebServices.asmx HTTP/1.1 \r\n";
 $header .= "Content-type: text/xml \r\n";
 $header .= "Content-length: ".strlen($post_string)." \r\n";
 $header .= "Content-transfer-encoding: text \r\n";
 $header .= "Connection: close \r\n\r\n"; 
 $header .= $post_string;

 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $header);

  $data = curl_exec($ch); 

 if(curl_errno($ch))
print curl_error($ch);
 else
    curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Comment: Are you getting anything back at all in data? Are you sure that the end point is doing everything properly?

Also, have you tried watching what goes on in a proxy like fiddler? 

Finally, you might want to not put the post into the headers by hand but use the proper setopt calls to set it to a post request and set the data.

Comment: You need to set security on your server. Your phpmyadmin is wide open to the internet and probably the rest of your server too. Do it NOW!!

Comment: In fact your whole XAMPP installation has no security set at all.

Answer (score 0):

When you write "it just comes back with a blank page " are you referring to a web browser response when you enter the url? If this is what you are referring to,  what web browser are you using?   I recommend you try different web browsers (Safari, FireFox, Chrome) and see what results you get.

Comment: and i get a blank page no matter what browser. . you can see for yourselg / /http://centos.dyndns.biz/test.php

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using headers to set a POST method and doing a custom request? Curl is perfectly capable of doing a POST as is:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
```

custom request is for when you want to do a less-common method, such as a HEAD or PUT request.

Comment: i really have no idea what im doing first time im messing with curl and php

Answer (score 0):

and PHP have SoapClient class to handle SOAP protocol. Are you sure you want to do it in hand-written manner, friend? :)

Comment: i have an .asp script that works beautifully ddoing this, but my client is running a linux server. can i maybe post my ASP script and someone transcode it for me . .those asp2php programs never work right.

Comment: your code up in question may look like: `$soap = new SoapClient(NULL, array('location' => 'http://www.geminifund.com/PubServices/WebServices/PublicationWebServices.asmx', 'uri' => 'http://www.geminifund.com/webservices/')); print_r($soap->__soapCall('GetHistroricalNav', array('startDate' => 'you arg', etc..)));` <br> By the way **GetHistroricalNav** - is there a typo?